# Spring Integration TCP force reconnect from both sides

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I recently received an answer on how I could force a reconnect from the client side (Client mode TCP connection factory and adapters).

But I also need to be able to close a connection from the server side (Server TCP connection factory and non-client-mode adapters).

I need to support a situation where, if some custom correlation logic goes out of sync, the connection is closed, and both sides react to this by resetting their counters etc.

So I need to:

1. Force a TCP disconnect from server
2. Force a TCP reconnect from client
3. Have the server code discover that the connection was
   closed from the client (is there an event or such?)
4. Have the client code discover that the connection was closed from the server
   (event?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3.0 release (currently at milestone 1) has a new [TCP Connection Eventing](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/whats-new.html) feature...

The M1 includes the functionality but the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events) was added after M1 and is available in the build snapshot.

You can either implement your own `ApplicationListener` or configure the new `<int-ip:tcp-connection-event-inbound-channel-adapter/>` which will send the events to a `<channel/>`.

Also, as is described in the [What's new](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/whats-new.html), you can now force close any connection, using it's id `connectionFactory.closeConnection(String connectionId)`.